# In Jupyter notebook when we read data from a .csv file and store it in a variable in what form is it stored? A list of rows or a dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, import-from-csv

#### my block code in jupyter notebook wherein data is being read from a .csv file

```
def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
        return list(reader)

enrollments = read_csv('enrollments.csv')
daily_engagement = read_csv('daily_engagement.csv')
project_submissions=read_csv('project_submissions.csv')
```

Comment: Please, choose a relevant title (don't put everything inside), and explain what's problem in your question

Answer (score 0):

Just introspect your variables in subsequent notebook cells:

```
enrollments
```

or:

```
type(enrollments)
```

or:

```
[type(e) for e in enrollments]
```

And so on.